# Issue with using useRef hook to scroll to a tab when there is no fixed number of tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

#### Steps to reproduce

Source code

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
import Tabs from '@mui/base/Tabs';
import TabsList from '@mui/base/TabsList';
import TabPanel from '@mui/base/TabPanel';
import { buttonClasses } from '@mui/base/Button';
import Tab, { tabClasses } from '@mui/base/Tab';
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import getDatesInMonth from '@/utils/getDatesInMonth';
import { dateContext } from '@/pages/mob';
import { useTabs } from '@mui/base';

export default function DayScrollView({ dates }) {
  const [activeDate, setActiveDate] = useContext(dateContext)
  const tabsRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const activeTab = tabsRef.current.querySelector(`.${tabClasses.root}[aria-selected="true"]`);
    console.log(activeTab)
    if (activeTab) {
      activeTab.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'center',
        inline: 'center',
      });
    }
  }, [activeDate, tabsRef])

  return <Box sx={
    {
      overflowX: 'scroll',
      scrollbarWidth: 'none',
      msOverflowStyle: 'none',
      '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
        display: 'none',
      },
    }
  }>
    <Tabs
      // ref={tabsRef}
      value={activeDate.toDateString()}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        console.log('Event type:', event.type);
        console.log('Target element:', event.target);
        console.log(`Tab ${newValue} was clicked.`);
        console.log(event)
        if (activeDate.toDateString() !== newValue) setActiveDate(new Date(newValue))
      }}>
      <StyledTabsList ref={tabsRef}>
        {dates.map((date, index) => {
          return (
            <StyledTab
              // disableRipple={true}
              key={date.toDateString()}
              value={date.toDateString()}

              onChange={() => console.log('CLICKED ' + date.toDateString())}>
              <Typography variant='subtitle1'>{date.toLocaleString('default', { weekday: 'short' })}</Typography>
              <Typography variant='h5'>{date.getDate()}</Typography>
            </StyledTab>
          )
        })}
      </StyledTabsList>
    </Tabs>
  </Box>
}

const StyledTab = styled(Tab)`
  color: #121212;
  cursor: pointer;
  ... more styles 

`;


const StyledTabsList = styled(TabsList)(
  ({ theme }) => `
  padding-right: 1rem;
  ... more styles 
  `,
);
```

The file using the above component

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { AppbarDayScreen } from '@/components/mobile/home/Navbar';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { createContext } from 'react';
import DayScrollView from '@/components/mobile/home/DayScrollView';
import getDatesInMonth from '@/utils/getDatesInMonth';


const dateContext = createContext()

export default function DayScreen() {
    const [activeDate, setActiveDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [dates, setDates] = useState(getDatesInMonth(activeDate))

    React.useEffect(() => { setDates(getDatesInMonth(activeDate)) }, [activeDate])
    return (
        <dateContext.Provider value={[activeDate, setActiveDate]}>
            <AppbarDayScreen />
            <DayScrollView dates={dates} />
        </dateContext.Provider>
    );
}

export { dateContext }
```

#### Current behavior

The function provided to `onChange` prop does not run when the `activeDate` changes. If this worked, I would have done things differently

```
//Inside the useEffect hook
const activeTab = tabsRef.current.querySelector(`.${tabClasses.root}[aria-selected="true"]`);
```

When the page loads the first time, `activeTab` refers to the active tab correctly.
But when `activeDate` is changed, the useEffect hook runs. But `activeTab` is still the previously active tab even though its `aria-selected` has become false when I log it in the next line

#### Expected behavior

`` tabsRef.current.querySelector(`.${tabClasses.root}[aria-selected="true"]`); `` should refer to the correct tab

#### Context

I have a horizontally scrollable tab
[image]

in the navbar, by clicking the `month` button, u can select a date and in the process change the `activeDate` (a useState variable)

The `activeDate` is passed to the tab component. I want to scroll to the tab with the specific date, whenever `activeDate` changes

Comment: If any more information needed, please write in comments

Comment: Not an answer b/c I'm not sure of the real cause, but one point that may help: `aria-selected` has likely become `false` when you log it because of the way inspector logging works -- it logs a reference to the element, not a snapshot of the element at the time you log it. In other words, at the time useEffect logs, `aria-selected` *is* true, but when you click the object in the inspector to see it, it pulls the *current* value. You can prove this to yourself by logging out the value in your `useEffect` (`console.log(activeTab.getAttribute('aria-selected'))`) instead of the the element itself.